# CPython and PyPy on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, cpython, pypy

I'm planning to install PyPy on my system. I already have CPython implementation existing on my system. Will installing PyPy affect this existing system implementation in any way ?

In nutshell, I want to know if PyPy and CPython an co-exist on any OS without any issues ? I'm attempting this on Mac OS X 10.6

Answer (score 2):

They can physically co-exist without any issue.

I am writing this in a system which has both Python 2.7.3, Pypy 1.9 and Python 3.2.3 installed.

Apart from that, Alex Martelli (who is an expert pythonista) in his book [Python in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596100469), seems to concur. To quote him:

> "Download and install all of them. They are free and coexist without
>   issues."

With **them** he refers to CPython, IronPython and Jython, but the same can apply to Pypy.

Also, you should not take my word for it. Download and install it and try it. Naturally, you won't have any issues.